Plot Interstate Highways using pyplot
Result image
I have written some code to plot states and counties. The original code does more, but I cut down the code I am using to a small form to post here. Below is the code to plot the counties in Utah.
I would like to plot the interstate highway system on this map. I have searched for information on how to do this, but I have been unsuccessful. Will someone point me to data I can use to plot this. I would especially like to have an example to plot on the map generated by the code below.
#! /usr/bin/python3

# Based on this YouTube video and the data from the US Census Bureau:
# https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X706iRqe1hA
# https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/time-series/geo/carto-boundary-file.html
#
# Projections:
# https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/reference/projections.html

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import numpy as np
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader
from metpy.cbook import get_test_data


def drawUtah():
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.Miller())
    ax.stock_img()

    for rec in shpreader.Reader(get_test_data('us_counties_500k.shp',
            as_file_obj=False)).records():
        fips_code = rec.attributes['GEOID']
        if(fips_code.startswith("49")):
            ax.add_geometries([rec.geometry], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                edgecolor='black', facecolor="#FFFAFA")

    ax.set_extent( (-114.75, -108.5, 36.5, 42.5) )
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.STATES)

    fig.savefig("./utah.png")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    drawUtah()


Update
After submitting the question 2 days ago (it was approved less than a day ago), I did some more searches. I FINALLY found the road data: https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/tiger-line-shapefile-2017-nation-u-s-primary-roads-national-shapefile
I downloaded the .zip file, extracted the files in the same directory as the source file, added code to read and plot it. New code appears below:
This update was added for the benefit of someone else searching for a solution to this problem. I have often searched and found answers I needed from years ago.
#! /usr/bin/python3

# Based on this YouTube video and the data from the US Census Bureau:
# https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X706iRqe1hA
# https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/time-series/geo/carto-boundary-file.html
#
# Projections:
# https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/reference/projections.html

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import numpy as np
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader
from metpy.cbook import get_test_data


def drawUtah():
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.Miller())
    ax.stock_img()

    for rec in shpreader.Reader(get_test_data('us_counties_500k.shp',
            as_file_obj=False)).records():
        fips_code = rec.attributes['GEOID']
        if(fips_code.startswith("49")):
            ax.add_geometries([rec.geometry], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                edgecolor='black', facecolor="#FFFAFA")

    for rec in shpreader.Reader("./tl_2017_us_primaryroads.shp").records():
        if(rec.attributes["FULLNAME"].startswith("I- ")):
            ax.add_geometries([rec.geometry], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                edgecolor='red', facecolor='#FF000000')

    ax.set_extent( (-114.75, -108.5, 36.5, 42.5) )
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.STATES)

    fig.savefig("./utah.png")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    drawUtah()


FYI: The new code is that second for loop.New result

If that answers your question, then you should post that as the answer and "approve" it.  As it stands now, I don't think you have a question any longer.

That is exactly what I did. Should I do something different?

If there is a question here, I don't see it.

Did you read what I wrote in the update portion? I agree that it should be closed because I FINALLY found the answer to my question. I also answered why it should remain.

You did not post a StackOverflow answer.  You edited the question to include an answer.  If you look at the bottom of this screen, there's a box labeled "Your Answer".  That's where your answer should go.
